# How do I create a new line using javascript that shows correctly in notepad?

Tags: javascript, newline, notepad

I have a script that copies table cells from the browser into the user's clipboard. I loop through each cell and when a new line is needed I use

```
text += "\n";
```

If I paste the text into excel, it formats correctly and fills in the proper rows, however if I paste into notepad, it shows a symbol instead of creating a new line:

123□456□789

instead of:

123

456

789

Is there something else I can use that notepad will recognize as a line break?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

that's because you need a carriage return and line feed.

```
text += "\r\n";
```

**The non programming way**
open up in WordPad
save
open in notepad

Comment: To clarify, "\n" is acceptable on *nix systems but Windows insists on both "\r\n". That's why you'll see some examples on the web that just use a line feed.

Comment: yes, you are 100% correct in your assumption.  Windows handles the whole CRLF thing differently, and the format of the files will be different depending on which system they were created on.  It's a hassle, I know.

Comment: Oddly this isn't working for me. Had just '\n' then added '\r\n' and still no dice in Notepad. However when I paste into Notepad++ and turn on show-all-characters I can see each (CR)(LF)! Very strange indeed.

Comment: Ah ha! My problem was caused by jQuery.val() on a textarea which apparently strips out the line breaks. May it be known!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
text += "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `\r\n` was not working with double qoutes `"` but instead single qoute `'` did the job like

```
 text += '\r\n';
```