# How to add new line in CSV generated by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, export-to-csv, jquery-csv

I have a list that needs to be generated as a CSV. Here it is:

```
[101, true, P, b, br, 2020], [101, true, P, 20, br, 2020], [101, true, P, b, breach, 2020]
```

And I wrote this to convert it:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.id = 'download-csv';
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(queries.toString().replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("],","\\r\\n").replaceAll(",",";").trim().replaceAll("]","")));
link.setAttribute('download', 'yourfiletextgoeshere.csv');
document.body.appendChild(link);
document.querySelector('#download-csv').click();
```

And generated a CSV file is like this:

```
101; true; P; b; br; 2020\r\n101; true; P; 20; br; 2020\r\n101; true; P; b; br; 2020
```

Instead of breaking the line, it continues as if `\r\n` is a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a new line using javascript that shows correctly in notepad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278501/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-using-javascript-that-shows-correctly-in-notepad)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897660/how-to-add-new-line-in-csv-generated-by-jquery#comment116517819_65897660) by user [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m), which OP responded 'solved' their problem:

Use this:

> `.replaceAll("],","\\r\\n") -> .replaceAll("],","\r\n")`